# problem with running of mysql image in docker

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile, dockerhub, ubuntu-20.04

I have such a problem, I'm trying to do master-slave replication according to this tutorial https://developpaper.com/master-slave-replication-of-mysql-based-on-docker/ .
There is no problem with the building of the image, but there is a problem with running this container. I can't get access to the mysql commands of mysql container in docker, it seems to be built from mysql (image from docker hub), but can not be started.
There are the following files:

> **Dockerfile:**

```
#Using MySQL image to create a new image
FROM mysql:latest

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD Kohc9hai

COPY start.sh /mysql/start.sh
COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf  
COPY init.sql /mysql/init.sql

EXPOSE 6603

CMD ["sh", "/mysql/start.sh"]
```

> **init.sql:**

```
--Create data_ Copy database
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `data_copy`;
CREATE DATABASE `data_copy` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_general_ci */;

--Create person table
USE `data_copy`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `person`;
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(32) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

> **my.cnf:**

```
[mysqld]
log-bin = mysql-bin
server-id = 1
```

> **start.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "start MySQL"
service mysql start
sleep 5

echo "initialize database"
mysql -uroot -pKohc9hai < /mysql/init.sql
echo "initialization complete"
tail -f /dev/null
```

By getting deeper, I think that I determined that the problem is in the file start.sh (Maybe I'm wrong).

> **There are logs of this container:**

```
start MySQL
mysql: unrecognized service
initialize database
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
initialization complete
```

Maybe someone can help me with the solution to this problem.
I'v just started to study Docker.

Answer (score 0):

> mysql: unrecognized service

From next, you could see there is no `mysql` service in container, so you surely failure:

```
$ docker run --rm mysql ls /etc/init.d
hwclock.sh
```

In fact, `mysql image` use [next](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L346) to start mysql service:

```
exec gosu mysql "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"
```

So you need to follow the same way.

**BUT**, for your scenario, looks you just customize `start.sh` to init some sql, while it's in fact already supported in official image:

> **Initializing a fresh instance** 
>
> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical order. You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

So, what you need to do is next in Dockerfile (Maybe need to specify MYSQL_DATABASE also):

```
COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Answer (score -1):

The document is quite old (docker version 1.13.1! Now 19.03.13!!). No special setting is required to use MySQL image. All you need to do is:

```
docker run --name foo -d -p 6603:6603 mysql:latest
```